# How to update time of an Android notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

I've got an Android notification which is updated every few minutes.

Firstly I create a `Builder` like that:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
```

And then, for first time when I show it and every time I update it, I use this code:

```
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
mBuilder.setContentText("Text");
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
manager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

But in the upper right corner of notification, Android still shows the time of when it was first displayed to the user. I'd like it to **show the time of the last update**. I know that it's possible because Facebook's Messenger app does that - changes the displayed time when a new message is sent.

How can I achieve that?

*Currently:*
[image: test]

Comment: Remember that in Java all code must be inside a class.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice well, I wouldn't post a screenshot if I didn't know about that. The notification is updated as it should be, just the time doesn't change

Comment: Yes, I understand your question. I am just providing a suggestion to help improve your question. For one thing, the class and method names provide more information about your code that helps us answer your question. You should also show how any methods are called if they are not Android callbacks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're probably looking for `NotificationCompat.Builder#setWhen(long)`. Supplying it with `System.currentTimeMillis()` should update the timestamp to the current time.

In addition if you want that timestamp to appear on Android N or higher, you need to call `NotificationCompat.Builder#setShowWhen(true)` at some point because it defaults to false.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#when

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can show time using below code

```
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(soundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Comment: You also need  `.setShowWhen(true)` as in the answer above.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha  Control whether the timestamp set with setWhen is shown in the content view. The default is true.